# While trying to sort columnwise in a portal application we are getting a exception

Tags: portal, webcenter

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "value" attribute on a region
>   component with id "null" was null or not specified thus its
>   RegionModel is null. Now using an empty RegionModel instead.

­

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The expression
>   "#{bindings.crcComplianceTF1.regionModel}" (that was specified for the
>   RegionModel "value" attribute of the region component with id "r1")
>   evaluated to null. This is typically due to an error in the
>   configuration of the objects referenced by this expression. If it
>   helps, the expression "#{bindings.crcComplianceTF1}" evaluates to
>   "null". If it helps, the expression "#{bindings}" evaluates to
>   "portal_homePageDef". Now using an empty RegionModel instead.

Attaching the J-Developer log

Comment: What kind of portal, what kind of data and what have you tried to do step by step?

Comment: It's a webcenter portal

Comment: Actually it is the issue with ADF dynamic Region which is coming into null

Comment: <ADF_FACES-60099> <The region component with id: r1 has detected a page fragment with multiple root components. Fragments with more than one root component may not display correctly in a region and may have a negative impact on performance. It is recommended that you restructure the page fragment to have a single root component.>

Comment: Please provide some updates as it is very urgent